# Oracle - update only one row without using rowid

Tags: oracle

I am trying to `update` a `view` table, but only the first result from it.
I cannot use `rowid` - not working on `view` table.
Is there a way to update only the first `row`? as I said using [rowid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244671/update-statement-in-oracle-using-sql-or-pl-sql-to-update-first-duplicate-row-onl)
solutions could not work.
`select` query example:

```
select addr
from addrView
where (tl = '7' and tr = '2')
```

returns 4 `results`, but when using `update`:

```
update addrView
set home='current'
where (tl = '7' and tr = '2')
```

I still want to upadte the first row.

Comment: use where rownum = 1

Comment: the first row, based on what sorting logic?

Comment: based on result set.

Comment: @MarcusH - rownum in the result query?

Comment: In your update query's where clause, add rownum = 1

Comment: trying and posting the result

Comment: isn't there any other way to identify the row?

Comment: no, the table is a view without the possibilty to uniqe identify  a row.

Comment: um, you could update the view to include the rowid(s) from the table(s) being queried?

Comment: No, rowid cannot work anyway on views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ROWID` is a unique identifier of each row in the database.

`ROWNUM` is a unique identifier for each row in a result set.

You should be using the `ROWNUM` version, but you will need an `ORDER BY` to enforce a sorting order, otherwise you won't have any guarantees what is the "first" row returned by your query and you might be updating another row.

```
update addrView
set home='current'
where (tl, tr) = (
   select tl, tr 
   from (select tl, tr
         from addrView 
         where (tl = '7' and tr = '2')
         order by col_1
             , col_2
             , col_3 etc.
        ) result_set
    where rownum = 1);
```

But, if you don't care about what data is in the first row returned by your query, then you can use only `rownum = 1`.

```
update addrView
set home = 'current'
where (tl = '7' and tr = '2')
    and rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Trying and posting the result.