# How to update a column with duplicate values in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have this `employee` table with some duplicate values. I want to change the `emp_address` with the new address.

But I want it to update only a single row.

```
emp_id | emp_name | emp_address | emp_dept
-------+----------+-------------+-----------
 101   |   Rick   |    Delhi    |   D001
 101   |   Rick   |    Delhi    |   D001
 123   |   Maggie |    Agra     |   D890
 166   |   Glenn  |    Chennai  |   D900
 166   |   Glenn  |    Chennai  |   D900
```

Comment: And which row do you want to update?

Comment: You want to update a single row with what?   Can you give start to the update statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UPDATE statement in Oracle using SQL or PL/SQL to update first duplicate row ONLY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244671/update-statement-in-oracle-using-sql-or-pl-sql-to-update-first-duplicate-row-onl)

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to use `LIMIT 1` on your update query.

edit: or use `ROWNUM <= 1` in Oracle

Comment: The question is tagged as `oracle`.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can update like below:

```
 update table
    set emp_address = (Select emp_address
                       from emp a
                       where a.rowid in (select max(rowid)
                                        from emp_address b 
                                         where a.emp_id = b.emp_id                   
                                        group by  emp_id,emp_name) )
where emp_id =101;
```